# Calculate difference in 2 values - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table that has 3 values (old, new & difference) I'm wondering how to calculate the difference in the 2 values to set the 'differenceInValues' variable. Thanks in advance!

```
<td scope="row">
  {{change.oldValue}}
</td>
<td scope="row">
  {{change.newValue}}
</td>
<td scope="row">
  {{change.differenceInValues}}
</td>
```

Comment: Can you give more information - what is in `oldValue` and `newValue`? The difference can be calculated for numbers quite simply (by subtracting them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this example will help you:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  {{value1}}
</div>
<div>
  {{value2}}
</div>
<div>
  {{getDiff()}}
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  value1: number = 5;
  value2: number = 3;

  getDiff(): number {
    return this.value1 - this.value2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend using methods in templates, even if its as simple as here. Store the result in a variable and then use String Interpolation to display it.

Comment: @jo-chris ok, you can use {{value1 - value2}} :)